# mysql select multiple and join query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have a complicated `MYSQL` query question here. I try my best to explain my problem.

I have 4 tables. mid is a foreign key between the tables. table4 is NOT a compulsory table source. However I like it returns all the rows even there are no match data from table4. So that I write a query script as following.

I'm not sure is it the logic way to write such query script but what I know that the syntax is wrong.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1, table2, table3, 
    (SELECT xx 
    FROM table4 
    RIGHT JOIN table1 ON table1.mid = table4.mid) 
WHERE table1.mid = table2.mid 
AND table1.mid = table3.mid 
AND tt = 'a' 
AND type = 1 
GROUP BY table1.mid 
ORDER BY xx DESC, table1.name ASC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do a left join between table1 & table4:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1
  JOIN table2 ON table1.mid = table2.mid 
  JOIN table3 ON table1.mid = table3.mid 
  LEFT JOIN table4 ON table1.mid = table4.mid 
 WHERE tt = 'a' 
   AND type = 1 
 GROUP BY table1.mid 
 ORDER BY xx DESC, table1.name ASC;
```

Comment: It's work charming. Thank expert!! :)
But is it the only way?

Comment: For your need, it's the way to do it (the standard & simplest way). Of course, there are other ways, more complicated but     uninteresting when you have `LEFT JOIN`.